# spring boot Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson

I want to use the following config to customize java8 localdatetime pattern

```
@Bean
@Primary
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {
    return builder -> {
        builder.simpleDateFormat(dateTimeFormat)
                .serializerByType(LocalDateTime.class,
                        new LocalDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimeFormat)))
                .deserializerByType(LocalDateTime.class,
                        new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimeFormat)))

                .serializerByType(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat)))
                .deserializerByType(LocalDate.class,
                        new LocalDateDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat)))

                .serializerByType(LocalTime.class, new LocalTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(timeFormat)))
                .deserializerByType(LocalTime.class,
                        new LocalTimeDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(timeFormat)));
    };
}
```

but not working,spring boot version 2.6.9,the project integrate spring cloud components like feing eureka and so on.but in my spring boot  project without spring cloud coponents,above config working,

[image]

finally i config the httpmessageconverters to resolve this issue,but i did not know why above config not working?

```
@Override
public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    // jackson单独配置,参考：https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000041997183
    converters.removeIf(converter -> converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);
    converters.add(0, mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);
}
```

Both projects EnableWebMVC and extends WebMvcConfigurer to config interceptors

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
```

Comment: It should work but there is too little information here. I suspect you added an `@EnableWebMvc` or extending `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration` or the likes, disabling auto-configuration leading to manually messing around with beans. However as said there is too little information to answer this.

Comment: Yes,both projects add @EnableWebMvc and implements WebMvcConfigurer,but do not extending DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration  neither.

Comment: Remove `@EnableWebMvc` as that disables the auto-configuration and thus the use of that specific customizer.

Comment: @M.Deinum is it possibile to apply Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer  without removing `@EnableWebMvc`? If I remove webmvc, spring-security config will not work in my app. Thanks

Comment: No, and adding `@EnableWebMvc` isn't the solution, proper configuration is (as a question about that with the error you are having).